# AJAX is not displaying anymore any modification on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just experienced an issue and I don't know where it comes from... The fact is that yesterday's evening, I began to code a website and everything was working fine.

This morning, I came at my desk, I opened my website and it worked. But it didn't worked as I expected : **no matter which changes i'm doing to a page, it doesn't seem to display or to be saved...**

So I'm wondering... Are my jQuery AJAX requests false, or I don't know what could it be.
Please note that I've checked many times if I were saving the file at the right spot, if it wasn't some JavaScript that fails on loading and if I didn't close a HTML tag and now I'm very short caught.

I'm using Bootstrap 3 Stylesheets, jQuery and jQuery-ui JavaScript with jQuery AJAX.

Here is my code :

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Sample title</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div id="navbar"></div>

        <div id="content"></div>

        <div id="footer"></div>

    </div>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "views/navbar.html",
                success: function(result){
                    $('#navbar').html(result);
            }});
            $.ajax({
                url: "views/cv.html",
                success: function(result){
                    $('#content').html(result);
            }});
            $.ajax({
                url: "views/footer.html",
                success: function(result){
                    $('#footer').html(result);
            }});
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

navbar.html is the default Bootstrap's navbar but with it inside it :

```
<script>    
$('#webdev').click(function(){
    function webdev_ajax()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'views/webdev.html',
            success: function(result){
                $('#content').html(result);
        }});
    }
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $('#li_webdev').addClass('active');
    $('#content').fadeOut().delay(600);
    setTimeout(webdev_ajax,600);
    $('#content').fadeIn();
});

$('#cv').click(function(){
    function cv_ajax()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'views/cv.html',
            success: function(result){
                $('#content').html(result);
        }});
    }
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $('#li_cv').addClass('active');
    $('#content').fadeOut().delay(600);
    setTimeout(cv_ajax,600);
    $('#content').fadeIn();
});
</script>
```

The cv.html hasn't really some content, only a 'p' tag with some text and it continues to display when it changes, but webdev.html is not displaying changes.

Here is the code of webdev.html :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 style="text-align:center;">HTML</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>
                Le HTML (Hyper Text Markup Language) est la base de tout projet internet : c'est le langage web permettant de mettre en forme
                du contenu web pour un site. Il est généralement couplé à d'autres langages afin d'en étendre les possibilités (CSS, PHP, JavaScript, etc...)
            </p>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td class="active"><b><center>Niveau</center></b></td>
                <td class="info"><center>Débutant - Utilisateur indépendant</center></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b><center>Connaissances prérequises</center></b></td>
                <td class="info"><center>Aucune</center></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="active"><b><center>Logiciels / fichiers requis</center></b></td>
                <td class="success"><center>Editeur de code<sup><a id="code_edit" href="#">?</a></sup></center></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <p style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Choisir</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 style="text-align:center;">JavaScript</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>
                Le JavaScript est un langage de script utilisé dans les pages web en général pour rendre celles-ci
                plus dynamiques. Ces scripts s'exécutent côté client (machine de l'utilisateur) et respectent la norme
                ECMA Script. Il existe des fonctionnalités supplémentaires permettant d'étendre le JavaScript vers le serveur.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <p style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Choisir</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 style="text-align:center;">jQuery</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <p style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Choisir</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var texte = "Un éditeur de code est un logiciel où vous pouvez éditer du texte.\nExemple : Notepad++, Netbeans, Sublime Text, etc...";
    $('#code_edit').prop('title',texte);
    $('#code_edit').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

If someone has an idea of where it comes from and why please let me know.

Comment: You would be better to use includes for this instead of AJAX.

Comment: Using includes will means using PhP and by the way having to refresh the page. I wanted to do a whole website without any refresh.

Comment: Given that you only load each page once on load, I don't see why a page refresh is required?

Comment: I don't load each page on load. I just load the home page on the dom load (which is cv.html) and then on navbar's link clicks I load other pages and insert the code of them in the 'content' div of index.html.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna: Don't add that much syntax highlighting. It makes the question less readable.

Comment: You can check with Browser tools if your Ajax request is failing.

Comment: I checked with Firebug (because I'm using Firefox) and requests are OK. And the webdev.html page displays but without my last changes.

Comment: try changing the webdev.html file name or using in the ajax call webdev.html?v=1

Comment: #BinaryGhost I changed the name into lesson.html and it is now working. Do you know why it happened ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your brower has cached the html webpage.
As you can see in the jquery documention:

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp') Type:
>   Boolean If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be
>   cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work
>   correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending
>   "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
>   other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
>   that has already been requested by a GET.

So you can add the paramater to the ajax options

```
cache: false
```

You can also just add paramater to the ajax request filename

```
webdev.html?v=1...
```

It will force the browser to load it

You can read more about ajax caching here:
https://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/08/07/ajax-caching-two-important-facts/